# Devolver el nombre de sólo una variable por iteración en R

Tags: r, loops

Estoy utilizando en R un lapply() con una función y, en lugar de obtener el nombre de la variable correspondiente a cada iteración, obtengo todos los nombres de las variables en cada iteración. Con

```
colnames(data) <- c("var1", "var2")

varnames <- function(var, name){
   return(name)
 }

print(lapply(data, varnames, name=names(data)))
```

La salida que obtengo es:

```
$var1
[1] "var1" "var2"

$var2
[1] "var1" "var2"
```

En cambio, quisiera obtener:

```
$var1
[1] "var1"

$var2
[1] "var2"
```

Comment: Hola Gabriel, puedes ser un poco más específico en lo que intentas hacer? Que debiese hacer la función `varnames`?

Comment: @jbkunst Hola! Simplemente devolver el nombre de la variable, en cada iteración el nombre de una variable y no el de todas las variables

Answer (score 1):

`lapply` y familia hacen el bucle por las **filas** del data.frame.

No tiene sentido usarlo para aplicarlo columna a columna. Para obtener lo que quieres puedes hacer:

`setNames(as.list(names(data)), names(data))`

Answer (score 0):

La función varnames que has definido pide los argumentos `var` y `name`, y devuelve el valor de `name`.

```
varnames <- function(var, name){
   return(name)
 }
```

`lapply` aplica una función a cada elemento de una lista. En el caso de los data.frame, sus elementos son las columnas, tal como está descrito en la documentación de la familia `apply` en R.

Con lo siguiente pides aplicar la función varnames a los elementos de data. Para cada aplicación de la función, estás estableciendo que el argumento name es igual a los `names(data)`.

```
lapply(data, varnames, name = names(data)
```

Por esta razón, al correr la función, te devuelve el valor de `names(data)`, pues esto es lo que le has pedido.

Para obtener el resultado que esperas, usando `lapply`, puedes usar lo siguiente.

```
lapply(1:length(data), function(x){
  names(data[x])
})
```

¿Porqué no `lapply(data, names)`?

Porque entonces `lapply` aplica names a cada elemento de `data`. En este ejemplo, esto es `data[[1]]` y `data[[2]]`, los cuales no tienen una propiedad `name`.

Esto es diferente a aplicar names a `data[1]` y `data[1]`, que sí tienen nombre.